# Pandas Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've seen many posts about my problem but non of them seem to solve it. I have two DFs identical in terms of columns (dfTemp.rows > dfLags.rows).

```
print(dfLags.columns.values)
print(dfLags.dtypes)
print(dfLags)
```

... produces ...

```
['Site ID' 'Port' 'outSpeed']
Site ID      object
Port         object
outSpeed    float64
dtype: object
        Site ID     Port     outSpeed
0     10.2.20.5  Lag 112  10000000000
1     10.2.20.5  Lag 122  10000000000
2     10.2.21.3    Lag 1   2000000000
3     10.2.21.3    Lag 3  20000000000
4     10.2.21.3   Lag 10  20000000000
5   10.2.22.123    Lag 2   3000000000
6   10.2.22.123    Lag 3   2000000000
7   10.2.22.123   Lag 10   6000000000
8    10.2.22.21    Lag 1   3000000000
9    10.2.22.21    Lag 3   2000000000
10   10.2.22.21   Lag 10   6000000000
11   10.2.46.52    Lag 3  20000000000
12   10.2.46.52   Lag 10  20000000000
```

On the other hand:

```
print(dfTemp.columns.values)
print(dfTemp.dtypes)
print(dfTemp)
```

... produces:

```
['Site ID' 'Port' 'outSpeed']
Site ID      object
Port         object
outSpeed    float64
dtype: object
          Site ID    Port    outSpeed
0      10.2.22.74   1/5/7  1000000000
1      10.2.22.74   1/1/7  1000000000
2      10.2.22.74   1/3/7  1000000000
3      10.2.22.74   1/4/7  1000000000
4       10.2.20.5   3/1/3  1000000000
5      10.2.46.52   3/2/1  1000000000
6      10.2.46.52  3/2/10  1000000000
7      10.2.46.52  Lag 10         NaN
8       10.2.21.3   1/1/1  1000000000
9       10.2.21.3   3/2/5  1000000000
10      10.2.21.3  Lag 10         NaN
..            ...     ...         ...
11    10.2.21.251   1/1/2  1000000000
181   10.2.22.123  1/2/21  1000000000
182   10.2.22.123  2/1/13  1000000000
183   10.2.22.123  2/1/14  1000000000
184   10.2.22.123  2/1/17  1000000000

[185 rows x 3 columns]
```

Whenever I try to compare, I get the error `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects`. I'm trying to do the following:

```
dfTemp.loc[ (dfTemp[[SITE_IP,PORT_NAME]]==dfLags[[SITE_IP,PORT_NAME]]) & (dfTemp["outSpeed"].empty), "outSpeed"] = \
dfLags.loc[ (dfTemp[[SITE_IP,PORT_NAME]]==dfLags[[SITE_IP,PORT_NAME]]) & (dfTemp["outSpeed"].empty), "outSpeed"]
```

Any hint on why am I getting such error?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, yes. Both dimensions must be identical for comparison. Otherwise, how can you expect pandas to compare when one has more rows than the other? What will the extra rows compare to?

Comment: In particular, the indexes must align along both axes.

Comment: As per the error, it looks to me that pandas it's complaining about the labels, not the mismatch in the amount of rows. It's confusing. Does it mean, then, that I'll be able to only compare same size DFs? It doesn't make any sense. I want to compare based on column names and extract info when there is a match along the rows (just like Excel's VLOOKUP). On the other hand, I don't follow you with the "In particular, the indexes must align along both axes". What do you mean?

Comment: Yes, because `df1 == df2` returns a mask of booleans. Also, I mean that df1.index == df2.index and df1.columns == df2.columns.

Comment: I think you need `df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Site ID', 'Port' ])`

Comment: If need match all columns use `df = pd.merge(df1, df2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

You need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
df = (dfTemp.set_index(['Site ID', 'Port'])
            .combine_first(dfLags.set_index(['Site ID', 'Port']))
            .reset_index())
```

---

```
print (df)
        Site ID     Port     outSpeed
0     10.2.20.5    3/1/3   1000000000
1     10.2.20.5  Lag 112  10000000000
2     10.2.20.5  Lag 122  10000000000
3   10.2.21.251    1/1/2   1000000000
4     10.2.21.3    1/1/1   1000000000
5     10.2.21.3    3/2/5   1000000000
6     10.2.21.3    Lag 1   2000000000
7     10.2.21.3   Lag 10  20000000000
8     10.2.21.3    Lag 3  20000000000
9   10.2.22.123   1/2/21   1000000000
10  10.2.22.123   2/1/13   1000000000
11  10.2.22.123   2/1/14   1000000000
12  10.2.22.123   2/1/17   1000000000
13  10.2.22.123   Lag 10   6000000000
14  10.2.22.123    Lag 2   3000000000
15  10.2.22.123    Lag 3   2000000000
16   10.2.22.21    Lag 1   3000000000
17   10.2.22.21   Lag 10   6000000000
18   10.2.22.21    Lag 3   2000000000
19   10.2.22.74    1/1/7   1000000000
20   10.2.22.74    1/3/7   1000000000
21   10.2.22.74    1/4/7   1000000000
22   10.2.22.74    1/5/7   1000000000
23   10.2.46.52    3/2/1   1000000000
24   10.2.46.52   3/2/10   1000000000
25   10.2.46.52   Lag 10  20000000000
26   10.2.46.52    Lag 3  20000000000
```

Comment: It does not completely work. If I do merge, I get an extra colum, with the merged data. I just want to fill the empty rows in dfTemp with the data from dfLags when both `Site_IP` and `Port`, match.

Comment: OOPs, I was wrong. I completely change answer, please check it.